# apt unwilling to upgrade my package

Tags: debian, apt

Here’s the output of `apt policy ppp`

```
ppp:
  Installed: 0.106
  Candidate: 0.106
  Version table:
     0.107 500
        500 http://ppp.com/buster/rel ./ Packages
 *** 0.106 999
        500 http://ppp.com/buster/rel ./ Packages
        999 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

As you see, the OS is aware there's a new version `0.107` I've just published on ppp.com, but for some reason it doesn't consider it to be a candidate.

`apt list --upgradable` prints nothing.

`sudo apt-get upgrade ppp` prints `ppp is already the newest version (0.106)`

**Update:** The hardware vendor who made the OS image has created the file `/etc/apt/preferences.d/99local` with the following content:

```
# Prefer local packages
Package: *
Pin: release a=now
Pin-Priority: 999
```

What’s the best way to allow upgrades for the few packages hosted on my repository at ppp.com?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To allow packages served by ppp.com to be upgrade candidates, you need to pin them to the same priority as local packages (or higher, but pin priorities of 1000 or more allow downgrades, which is usually not desirable). Add a file in `/etc/apt/preferences.d` with the following contents:

```
Package: *
Pin: origin "ppp.com"
Pin-Priority: 999
```

If you don’t want to change pin priorities, you can still upgrade packages by explicitly requesting a target version:

```
sudo apt install ppp=0.107
```

Depending on the support contract you have with the hardware manufacturer, or warranty conditions etc., you may want to delete `/etc/apt/preferences.d/99local` altogether — pinning local packages to such a high priority is rarely useful, and it prevents external upgrades from being installed.

Comment: The workaround with that extra config file worked like a charm. Thanks a lot for your help. I didn’t want to request exact versions because it would complicate my code. The end users are probably unaware that piece of industrial equipment is a computer running Debian Linux. Instead, they have “check for updates” touchscreen button in the preferences screen on their device, implemented by running a few `apt` commands.

Comment: Yup, I understand, I wanted to cover both approaches ;-).